# Primary key violation when using active admin Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am learning Ruby on Rails using a very simple blog application, and I just got active admin to work. While adding a new category, I keep getting
*ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique* in *Admin::CategoriesController#create*.

Records already exist in the categories table, so there is a violation. But the id is database generated and should it not use persist a unique value. I have added the *permit_params* in my categories admin controller.

#### Categories admin controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
permit_params :id, :name
end
```

I don’t know how to specify that the id is the primary key and should be database generated. It worked fine when I use the normal means of persisting, this is my regular categories controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :category_params, :only [:create, :new]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @title = @category.name;
    @posts = @category.posts;
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
          params.require(:category).permit(:name);
      end

end
```

Also if there are four categories in the table, after four violations it submits the fifth time as there isn't any violation any more.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:id` from the permitted parameters.

ActiveRecord handles that for you.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  permit_params :name
end
```

Comment: That did not work. I tried it for my posts admin controller like `permit_params :title, :body, :category_id` but still threw the violation error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Admin::PostsController#create
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "posts_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(3) already exists. : INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"`

Comment: Like I said, if I keep doing this it will eventually insert something unique and the problem goes away but I dont know why the db generation for the key is not working

Comment: Can you post the **migration that created the table** ?
There has to be something wrong on the DB level, because the INSERT statement seems find and does not even send the `id`.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont have all the necessary code any more. I had to delete and redo everything.... Apologies